# How Do I find the LCD for the following problem 9/48 + 3 /54?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

\begin{align*}
48 & = 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 3\\
54 & = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 3
\end{align*}

If I take the prime number from both numbers that appears most often and multiply them together I get $432$.

This seems pretty large. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Your only mistake is calling it LCD. $432$ is the LCM.

Comment: Okay, what is the differnce?

Comment: LCM - the smallest number which is divisible by each one of them without a remainder. LCD - the smallest number which divides each one of them without a remainder.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help-

Comment: Well, $\frac{1}{432} = \gcd(\frac{1}{48}, \frac{1}{54})$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The least common denominator of $\frac{..}{48}$ and $\frac{..}{54}$ is the smallest number divisible by both $48$ and $54$.  Like you wrote it:

$$48 = 16\cdot 3 = 2^4 \cdot 3\\
54= 2 \cdot 27 = 2 \cdot 3^3$$

so the common denominator is $2^4 \cdot 3^3 = 2^3 \cdot (2 \cdot 27) = 8 \cdot 54 = 432$

Seems OK.

Obs: when adding fractions, you may  reduce each fraction to lower terms before adding, like @ajotatxe: showed.

Answer (score 0):

LCD is "lesat common divisor", which is always $1$. What you must compute is LCM (least common multiple). The number that you have found, $432$, is in fact the least common multiple, and is what you must do to add those fractions.

**BUT** the fractions are not in their least terms: you should simplify them before adding:

$$\frac9{48}+\frac3{54}=\frac3{16}+\frac1{18}=\ldots$$

Comment: Here LCD means Least Common Denominator. I've never heard it used as you say.